# Creating a Select Menu in bash using JSON input

Tags: json, bash

I am trying to create a menu using the select function in bash. I am accessing an API which will return its output in json format. I will then process what the API returns into a select statement where a user can then interact with.

Here is the API call and how I parse the output:

```
curl -H "Authorization:Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" https://api.runscope.com/buckets \
| python -mjson.tool > output.json
```

This will send the output from the curl through python's json parsing tool and finally into the output.json file.

I then create an array using this json blob. I had to set IFS to \n in order to parse the file properly:

```
IFS=$'\n'
BUCKETS=("$(jq '.data | .[].name' output.json)")
```

I then add an exit option to the array so that users have a way to quit the selection menu:

```
BUCKETS+=("Exit")
```

Finally, I create the menu:

```
select BUCKET in $BUCKETS;
do
  case $BUCKET in
    "Exit")
      echo "Exiting..."
      break;;
  esac
  echo "You picked: $BUCKET"
done
```

Unfortunately, this does not create the exit option. I am able to see a menu consisting of every other option I want, except the exit option. Every option in the menu and in the array has quotes around them. How do I get the Exit option to show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$BUCKETS` is expanding to the *first* element of the `BUCKETS` array.

Which is then being word-split and used as your select entries.

This makes sense since you wrapped the `jq` subshell in double quotes which prevented word-splitting from happening there (and means the `IFS` change isn't doing anything I believe).

**Iff** your entries can contain spaces **and** you want that assigned to an array properly the way to do that is by reading the output of `jq` with a `while IFS= read -r entry; do` loop.

```
BUCKETS=()
while IFS= read -r entry; do
    BUCKETS+=("$entry")
done < <(jq '.data | .[].name' output.json)
```

Then appending your exit item to the array.

```
BUCKETS+=(Exit)
```

and then using

```
select BUCKET in "${BUCKETS[@]}"; do
```

(Both `select a in l; do` or `select a in l\ndo` there's no need for `;` *and* `\n` there.)

That all being said unless you need `output.json` for something else you can avoid that too.

```
BUCKETS=()
while IFS= read -r entry; do
    BUCKETS+=("$entry")
done < <(curl -H "Authorization:Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" https://api.runscope.com/buckets | python -mjson.tool | jq '.data | .[].name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
jq '.data | .[].name' output.json
```

try

```
jq -r '.data | .[].name' output.json
```

(`-r` : raw data without quotes)

And the most important part :

```
select BUCKET in "${BUCKETS[@]}"
                          ^^^
                         ARRAY syntax
```

Comment: This doesn't address the wrapping quotes around the `jq` command which means this will just make the select menu two entries: everything `jq` returned and `Exit`.

Comment: @EtanReisner Is correct about his point. But in order to fix that, I just had to remove the quotes surrounding the Array syntax you pointed out in your answer.

Comment: @honestemu3 Removing the quotes around the array expansion still leaves word splitting happening and your elements cannot contain spaces. Using quotes on the array expansion is **correct** usage. You've opted yourself in to doing something wrong by quoting the `jq` call in the first place. See my answer. (Oh, not only spaces won't work. Shell metacharacters will cause problems also.)